# Is it possible to take a list of usernames and search for and export specific Active Directory information?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

so I have a list of about 1100 usernames in AD and I was wondering if someone could point me towards a powershell command to use the list of usernames to get Client IP Addresses, Client Host Names, the last logon time, and login successes/failures, then export the results as a table in excel. If there's no way to do this with a powershell command/script, is there a way to filter results by the list of usernames in ADAudit? Thanks a ton.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: if you have SCCM/MECM, that would be where I look to get this info...

Answer (score 0):

On an Active Directory computer client with PowerShell 5.1 and Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise install the Optional Feature 'RSAT: Active Directory Domain Services and Lightweight Directory Services Tools'.
Then open a PowerShell console and run Get-ADUser cmdlet. I suggest you then, go and read this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps . This will give you almost whatever you need.